# cohomology of exterior powers of tangent bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $G$ is a Grassmannian variety. Let $T_G$ be the tangent bundle.
Then $H^0(G,T_G)$ is non zero. I wondered if one knows $H^0(G,\wedge^iT_G)$, for $i>0$.

THanks

Answer (score 7):

You need Borel--Bott--Weil Theorem. It gives the following answer: if $G = G(k,n)$ then $H^0(G,\Lambda^m_G)$ is the direct sum over all Young diagrams $\alpha = (a_1,\dots,a_k)$ inscribed in an $(n-k)\times k$ rectangle with $m$ boxes of the highest weight representations of the group $GL_n$ with highest weight $(a_1,\dots,a_k,-b_{n-k},\dots,-b_1)$, where $\beta = (b_1,\dots,b_{n-k})$ is the transposition of $\alpha$.

Comment: Should Bott really be a part of it? I mean computing $H^0$ :)